# Shell script for monitoring the sever

Tags: shell, monitoring

Can someone please give shell script for this scenario. I need to check below Server/URL is up or not.
If my server is up no need to trigger any alert .. if my server is down .. Alert should be triggered by stating my server is down.

http://18.216.40.147:5555/

```
#!/bin/bash
addr=18.216.40.147
if ! curl -v -u 'Administrator:******' https://"$addr":5555 | grep HTTP/1.1 200; then 
    echo "Server is down" | mailx -s "server is down" "******@gmail.com"
    echo "Server is down" >&2
fi
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service.  Try to write your own script, then update the question with what you tried and any specific problems you hit.

Comment: HI @StephenNewell, Attached the code.. could you please check and assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*curl* can return only http response code, then you can compare with right answer:

```
#!/bin/bash

addr="http://18.216.40.147:5555/"
answer=$(curl -o /dev/null -s -w '%{http_code}\n' $addr)

if [ $answer -eq 200 ]
then
  echo "UP"
else
  echo "DOWN"
fi
```

Comment: Please see my improvements to your answer.

Comment: Hi @DudiBoy, can you please explain -s -w ... why we used that parameters ?

Comment: -s = silent mode; and 
-w = format output (to return only http response code)

Comment: Now we are checking for https server.
The server is down , we are getting alert. In another case, server is up but we are getting down alert. If we are changing https addr, do we need to change any thing  ?

Comment: 1. If you use some self-signed certificate, you may need to add the -k parameter to bypass the ssl check.

2. Pay attention, not all URLs will answer 200 code. If the page requere a login, it can return a redirect (30X) or another error. Check for your situation which code is returning.

Comment: so i have to pass the -k parameter in curl ?

like this curl -k ?

Comment: We don't know exact your problem, so: #1. Check your http return code. Maybe your problem is the URL is returning another code instead 200; #2. If you received 000 as code or a error about certificate, add -k parameter (... -k -s -w ...)

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting @[Juarnir Santos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10424004/juranir-santos) is essentially correct but need some improvements:

1. If server is down or network configuration is blocking access to server, you want to timeout the request for 4 (or more) seconds.
2. Bash testing for numbers requires `[[` numerical expression `]]`

Therefore the improved answer is:

```
#!/bin/bash

addr="http://18.216.40.147:5555/"
answer=$(timeout 4 curl -o /dev/null -s -w '%{http_code}\n' $addr)

if [[ $answer -eq 200 ]]; then
  echo "UP"
else
  echo "DOWN"
fi
```